# MVC3 Entity Connection string disappearing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config, connection-string

I am having a very frustrating problem with my current project. It is continually losing the connection string binding for Entity models.

I have multiple models for different databases in separate areas and was having no problems. Suddenly now whenever I try to update from the database I get the connection string setup prompt. I select for it to add it to the Web.config with the password but it doesn't ever pick it up there again. They all are still in the web config but it just doesn't see them.

If I remove all the connection strings from the config file it will write the new one there. Then when I try to set up a Stored procedure/Function Import, I still get the statement in the lower box:

```
No database connection has been configured for this model.
```

I have tried rebuilding the project and creating the models again from scratch and that works for a while. When I try and bring the project in under Perforce source control, it winds up getting re-corrupted & the connection string goes away. It affects all of my models too.

I am also using EF 4.x DbContext Generator to create context files. They work fine. I am also able to run the application and it connects to the database just fine and returns data. No issues there. I am just unable to update Entity Complex types from the DB or import any more stored procedures.

An even weirder occurrence was that I opened a broken project from a different directory then opened an uncorrupted copy it instantly became broken also. Contagious!

Any thoughts on where to look into to see why this is happening? Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: Is your model in the same project as your MCX code? Also try deleting your OBJ and BIN folders.

Comment: It's all in the same project. I tried deleting both the bin and obj but no dice. Still no connection string.

Comment: I also have noticed it all started when I added a model for a database on a different SQL server than the ones I had already in my project. Might that be a clue to this?

Comment: Do they have the same container name?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found where the issue is coming from.

I seem to have a bad value somewhere in my web.config which causes the issue. Here is the work around I found did the trick and showed it's the config:

- When the binding breaks, I closed the project then swapped out the web.config  with one from a good build which was missing a couple keys but worked well enough to bind.
- I reopen the the solution and the "No database connection..." error goes away.
- Then while the solution is still open I re-swap the web.config back in and it still works.

This is far from optimal but I can work until I figure out the bad value via doing some compares.

I will comment on this again once I determine the exact issue.